# Need to make a specific column editable upon clicking edit

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, insert-update

I have a gridview with "Edit Update Cancel" command field. 
When I click Edit, all the columns in the particular row becomes editable.
I just need to have 2 specific columns editable.  How is that made possible ?

(Screen Shot Attached)

[image]

[In the screen shot all 3 columns are editable, I just need the second and third to be editable]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the other columsn to read-only:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy. The column you want not editable then place just label and bind properly.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice", "{0:c}") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Here I use label in my `EditItemTemplate` because when the user clicks on edit button, the textbox will not come up. Rather, the value for that record will show through label, and as a result the user can not update that field.

Comment: @Thomas..Thanks  +1 as your solution will work..But Iam accepting previous answer as it is easier to implement.

Comment: when my answer was right then u can also leave a vote for me. anyway thanks.